# openconnect, ssl connection failure

Tags: openconnect

I have ocserv setup on a vm, but when trying to connect through openconnect app getting these errors,
it will be helpful if any solution, tried various ocserv config file modifications but non-sucessfull

Logs:

```
` Disconnected 
 STAT: attempt=O; first-NEVER; prev=NEVER 
 STAT: connect=o; first-NE-VER; prev=NEVER 
 STAT: cancel=o; first=NEVER; prev=NEVER 
 LIB: POST https://<IP/hostname>/ 
 L1B: Attempting to connect to server <IP/hostname>
 LIB: Connected to <IP :443/hostname> 
 LIB: SSL negotiation with <IP/hostname> 
 L1B: Server certificate verify failed: certificate does not match hostname CALLBACK: onValidatePeerCert
 LIB: SSI- connection failure: The operation timed out 
 LIB: Failed to open HTTPS connection to <IP/hostname> 
 Error obtaining cookie 
 VPN terminated with errors`
```

Update::: after few changes this is the current error im getting,
setup description: Vm has debian 9 installed with ocserv installed, also certificates. trying to connect useing openconnect android app, device has mobile data enabled with low speed.

Log:

```
   Disconnected
   STAT: attempt=O; first-NEVER; prev=NEVER
   STAT: connect=o; first-NE-VER; prev=NEVER
   STAT: cancel=o; first=NEVER; prev=NEVER
   LIB: POST https://<IP/hostname>/ 
   L1B: Attempting to connect to server <IP/hostname>
   LIB: Connected to <IP :443/hostname> 
   L1B: SSL_negotiation with <IP/hostname>
   L1B: SSL_connection failure: The operation timed out
   L1B: Failed to open HTTPS connection to <IP/hostname>
   Error obtaining cookie
   VPN terminated with errors
```

Is their any SSL issue? or do I need to give 3rd party SSL to ocserv, if so how to install 3rd party SSL to ocserv.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should add more information to make it easier to help you. How have you installed and which versions are you using?

Comment: thanks @JonasEberle for the reply i have edited my question hope it gives some more clarity

Comment: Your second log is unclear. There was a timeout during SSL handshake. I don't know what happened there. In the first one it is a certificate hostname mismatch which would be easy to remedy.

Comment: Was my answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

The error message states that the server's certificate did not match its hostname. As your client checks this, you need to use a certificate that matches the hostname that you use to access the server.